# Finding a python print function

Tags: python, python-2.7

**Background**

I have a print statement in some code (with many contributors). It is printing:

```
<soapenv:Body><QueryPerf xmlns="urn:vim25"><_this type="PerformanceManager">PerfMgr</_this><querySpec><entity type="VirtualMachine">vm-1442</entity><startTime>2019-05-21T11:32:32.362213-04:00</startTime><endTime>2019-05-22T11:32:32.362213-04:00</endTime><metricId><counterId>2</counterId><instance></instance></metricId><intervalId>300</intervalId></querySpec></QueryPerf></soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

for the life of me, I can't find out where this print statement is.

Its a large python program with many files and its even possible that someone edited a library.

**Question**

Is there some way to tell a python program to print the location of the print statements that it is executing?

**Notes**

I've tried grepping around. Judging by the fact that this is a SOAP command my guess is that it is related to pyvmomi

**My Solution that worked for me (by some luck)**

ctrl C during the execution when the code was printing.

This is a horrible answer in general.

Comment: Maybe overwrite `print` (after import from `__future__`) to add some context information, like the name of hte module that is printing?

Comment: I agree with @tobias_k. Monkey patch `print` and use `inspect.stack()`

Answer (score 0):

if you know what print could have resulted in that (eg print(Alice)) and you're using pycharm you can use ctrl+shift+f to search in all files (same as ctrl+f in web).

Comment: Only works with a literal string. What about `print(var_with_soapenv)`?

Comment: it's exactly the same thing as a classic ctrl+f expect it's on all the projects files.(not on the imported library so)

Comment: OP said that they had already been "grepping around", which is basically "strg+f on all the files" on the command line. And this will not help if all you know is that it's probably some `print` statement (and not even that is sure; could also be a `sys.stdout.write`). It is _obvious_ that the `print` statement will _not_ contain the exact literal text that it is printing, in the code.